# how to enable previous form after closing current form in java

Tags: java

i have 2 forms. i'm done with: in Form1, i had a button to open Form2 without closing this Form1. i'd just disabled the Form1 for atleast i may not click it accidentally..

My problem is: in Form2, i also had a button to open Form1 and close the current form which is Form2. But when i had already close the Form2, the Form1 is still disabled.. my codes in button for Form2 >>
Form1 nf2 = new Form1(); nf2.setEnabled(true); this.dispose();

i know this is so simple, but help me guys.. thanks.

Comment: Let revise your questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to close the From1 after clicking the button in it, and do the same with the Form2, what means that the From1 will disappear and Form2 will show up, and the same with Form2.

Try this :
in Form1 (Button action listener):

```
(New Form2()).SetVisible(true);
dispose();
```

in From2 (Button action listener):

```
(New Form1()).SetVisible(true);
dispose();
```

Comment: but i will use my Form1 as my menu.. and the following forms will just pop-up in front of Form1.

Comment: You can use a JDialog instead of a JFrame and dialog.setVisible(true) will block until the dialog is closed. But if you want to make a menu for multiple JFrames (you don't want to block it with 1 From opened), then you'll need to check if an instance of the From2 exists, by storing them in a vector for example.